# jQuery AJAX return variable + value possible?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I'm submitting a form via jQuery.ajax()

Now my **PHP** script is checking if a specific input field is empty, example:

```
$is_error = $user->is_error;

if($is_error !=0)
 { 
    echo $is_error;
 }
```

Back to my jQuery.ajax() , I'd like to check if the value of $error was true or not, within the *sucess:* part of the jQuery.ajax() call.

```
   jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "edit.php", 
           data: jQuery("#idForm").serialize(),
           success: function(data)
       {   

        // show response from the php script if there is an error message
        // like:
        //         if(is_error) {show specific error message}
        //         else {show everything positive message}

       }
    });
```

Is it possible to check the PHP variable's value in there? Like if/else ?

Best regards!

Comment: What are you returning in the response? `console.log(data);` Return back what you need.

Comment: You need to echo the value back as the AJAX response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($_POST['name'] == "") 
  {
    $error = 1;
  }
else 
  {
    $error = 0;
  }
echo $error;
```

This code will echo the value.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "edit.php", 
           data: jQuery("#idForm").serialize(),
           success: function(data)
       {   

        // show response from the php script if $error == 0 or $error == 1.
        if(data==1)
....
       }
    });
```

Then you check what is the returned value.

Comment: Okay, but what if I have following construction:   '$is_error = $user->is_error;

  if($is_error !=0){
    echo $is_error;
  }'  Now how possible to if I don't know the exact error message? How can then the if(data==?) statement be?

Answer (score 1):

With your variable data, you can return values from PHP. And after in your scope success you can check.

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo the error so that it can be returned as data.. The ajax only returns what has been created in html..

Answer (score 0):

In instances like this I would use the following:

```
if($_POST['name'] == "") 
  {
    $error = 1;
  }
else 
  {
    $error = 0;
  }

echo $error;
```

jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "edit.php", 
           data: jQuery("#idForm").serialize(),
           success: function(response)
       {

```
    if(response == 1){
        alert('Error');
    }else{
        alert('No error');
    }

   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try the following in php script

```
echo $error;
```

and then in jquery.ajax() do

```
success: function(data){
 //data is $error
}
```